# Google Search Console Sitemap Errors in redirects

Tags: google-search-console

I have a short url website with over 700.000 shorts urls in it. I have created sitemaps for these short urls which i have uploaded to Google Search Console. the short urls looks like the examples bellow and every short url looks like this. This is a niche site which only redirect to one specific site. The problem is that when I look in google Search Console i get a lot of "pages with errors". When I check these urls, every url with an error exists and is active.

Why am I getting error from the sitemaps, and how can I remove them, or to get indexed properly?

**Short url example**

```
htts://site.com/45za
htts://site.com/45xa
htts://site.com/41cf
```

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it there.